# HOST="http://127.0.0.1:5984" in couchDB documentation

Tags: curl, couchdb

I'm very new to CouchDB and curl, and I've been working from the CouchDB documentation to get the basics. It's going okay so far, but I'm now stuck!

In Section 1.6 Authentication, 1.6.1 Creating New Admin, User there's a code example:

```
> HOST="http://127.0.0.1:5984"<br>
> curl -X PUT $HOST/database<br>
{"ok":true}
```

The first line isn't working. I get the following error:

```
'HOST' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I assume that I'm missing something here. **Can someone please point me in the right direction?**

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using Windows command prompt, so adjust the variable declarations:

```
set HOST="http://127.0.0.1:5984"
curl -X PUT %HOST%/database
```

The example you provided looks like it's intended for a unix console.

Comment: Success! Thanks user9570476. The author of the Getting Started guide appears to make a few omissions and assumptions, probably to keep the documentation concise and not too wordy.

Comment: I've now installed uBuntu for the first time to get around the syntax issues with Windows command prompt. but having another problem.
In the documentation...
curl -X PUT $HOST/_node/$NODENAME/_config/admins/anna -d '"secret"'
I figured out that nodename is the database (it's called "database" in this example) but I get an error " {"error":"nodedown","reason":"database is down"} ". Any ideas on the cause and how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: You'll need to get the list of NODENAME values for your server. You can do that with `curl -X GET $HOST/_membership`

Comment: Example output:
`{"all_nodes":["couchdb@localhost"],"cluster_nodes":["couchdb@localhost"]}` where couchdb@localhost is what you would set NODENAME to.